# How to get the user selected values from array in UITableView and pass that values to server

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have two arrays of dictionaries

```
    1. Array of categories

        [{
          "Category_ID": "1",
          "Category_en": "Event1",
        }, 
        {
          "Category_ID": "4",
          "Category_en": "Event4",
        },
        {
          "Category_ID": "9",
          "Category_en": "Event9",
        }]

    2.Array of cities
        [{
          "City_id": "1",
          "City_name": "Place1",
        }, 
        {
          "City_id": "2",
          "City_name": "Place2",
        },
        {
          "City_id": "4",
          "City_name": "Place4",
        }]
```

I am displaying values from these array in two tableViews and users can select multiple items, means cities and categories they want. How can i get user selected cities, categories and pass that id values to the url to get the result from the server

if i am getting the seleted rows by this method as an array , how can i append the corresponding `id` from cities and categories to the url

```
let list = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath]
```

this is the url to get the results from the server

```
   example : category_id=1,9&city_id=2,4

   http://www.events/events/searchEventsByCategory?category_id=1,9&city_id=2,4
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried using `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`?

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edited question

Comment: Are you asking about how to construct the url string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a categoriesTableView, citiesTableView  and your arrays are named categoryArray and cityArray

```
//create string of selected categories
let list = categoriesTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath];
let categoryIds = "";
for (let indexPath in list) {
    if (categoryIds.length == 0) {
        categoryIds = categoryArray[indexPath.row]["Category_ID"])
        continue
    }
    categoryIds = "\(categoryIds),\(categoryArray[indexPath.row]["Category_ID"])"
}

//create string of selected cities
list = citiesTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath];
let citiesIds = "";
for (let indexPath in list) {
    if (citiesIds.length == 0) {
        citiesIds = cityArray[indexPath.row]["City_id"])
        continue
    }
    citiesIds = "\(citiesIds),\(cityArray[indexPath.row]["City_id"])"
}
```

And your URL will be like:

```
let url = "http://www.events/events/searchEventsByCategory?category_id=\(categoryIds)&city_id=\(citiesIds)"
```

Comment: Tell me what exactly is not working? Which URL it creates?

Answer (score 1):

make 2 an array and add selected index directory into array

say selectedcategories and selectedcities

in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//add selected dictory in selectedArray

}
```

and after selections make string of by adding for loop

Comment: Thank you. Can you point out any examples doing the same or related this.